# how to use custom fields in line items within commercetools platform

Tags: commercetools

I actually have to add some custom fields to every line item within the commercetools platform.

Line Item Docs => http://dev.sphere.io/http-api-projects-carts.html#line-item

There I found this: => http://dev.sphere.io/http-api-projects-custom-fields.html#custom-fields

But apparently the docs for custom-fields are way too less in terms of showing "how to use them". Does somebody has any experience with that? A json example would be wonderful, with a bit more explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way we also got this new FAQ here on that topic that is hopefully proving helpful: http://dev.sphere.io/dev/tutorial-custom-types.html

Answer (score 2):

you can create a custom type for line items using the resource type ID "**line-item**" or "**custom-line-item**" (http://dev.sphere.io/http-api-projects-custom-fields.html#customizable-resource ) - example:

```
 {
  "key": "myLineItemType",
  "name": { "en": "my line item type" },
  "resourceTypeIds": ["line-item"],
  "fieldDefinitions": [
    {
      "type":{
          "name":"LocalizedString"
      },
      "name":"myField",
      "label":{
        "en":"my field",
        "de":"mein feld"
      },
      "required":false,
      "inputHint":"SingleLine"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then there are 2 ways of using the new custom type and the new field.

1. You can set the custom type and a value at the time you create a line item using the "**addLineItem**" Update action on the cart resource - see this JSON example for instance:

   ```
   {
     "version": 19,
     "actions": [{
       "action": "addLineItem",
       "productId": "9f19f37d-ec10-4ccf-9ff8-e5a295de0c3e",
       "variantId": 1,
       "quantity": 1
     }],
     "custom": {
           "typeKey": "myLineItemType",
           "fields": {
             "myField": {
               "en":"whats up",
               "de":"was ist los"
             }
           }
        }
   }
   ```
2. You can set the custom type of the line item with the "**setLineItemCustomType**" update action on the cart to make the field available. This can work with existing line items.

http://dev.sphere.io/http-api-projects-carts.html#set-line-item-custom-type

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create type using lineitem. Please follow below json to create type.
{

```
        "key": "apLineItemCustomFields",
        "name": {
            "en": "Line Item"
        },
        "description": {
            "en": " when custom fields or actions ."
        },
        "resourceTypeIds": [
            "line-item"
        ],
        "fieldDefinitions": [
            {
                "name": "order-status",
                "label": {
                    "en": "order-status"
                },
                "required": false,
                "type": {
                    "name": "String"
                },
                "inputHint": "SingleLine"
            },
            {
                "name": "productLanguage",
                "label": {
                    "en": "Product Language"
                },
                "required": false,
                "type": {
                    "name": "String"
                },
                "inputHint": "SingleLine"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Using above json it will create 2 custom fields in lineitem(String type).

Use set custom field in cart API
{

```
"actions": [
    {
        "action" : "setCustomField",
        "name" : "productLanguage",
        "value" : "English"
      }
]
```

}

you need to fill custom field value using this json.